# How can I do a calculation and substitute to binding variable using the value selected by picker?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made the Picker which have the range while -100 to 100, and the Picker's initial value is the 0.

But, the picked value(pickedX) are set the index 0 to 200 in this code.
It means that the pickedX is 100 when the 0 is selected in Picker.

So, I want to subtract 100 from pickedX, and
substitute the original x.

-> `x = pickedX - 100`

However, I get an error like this.

`Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'`

How can I do a calculation and substitute to binding variable using the value selected by picker?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct xdouble: View {
    
    @Binding var x: Int
    
    @State private var pickedX:Int = 100
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                
                Text("X")
                Picker(selection: self.$pickedX, label: Text("x")){
                    ForEach(-100..<100){ _x in
                        Text(_x.description)
                    }
                    x = pickedX - 100 // I want to subtract 100 from pickedX
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width / 2)
                .clipped()

                Text(self.pickedX.description) //debug view

            }
        }
    }
}

struct xdouble_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        xdouble(x: .constant(0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `id` in the ForEach to tag each item with their value.

```
Picker(selection: self.$pickedX,
label: Text("x")){
    ForEach(-100..<100, id:\.self) { number in
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
```

`@State pickedX` will be in range from -100 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed property.

```
var displayX: Int {
    return pickedX - 100
}
```

and then in body for display

```
Text(self.displayX.description)
```